# Printing input satisfying a particular made function

Tags: python, function, primes

So I defined a function for checking whether a number is prime or not :

```
def prime(num):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, num // 2):
            if num % i == 0:
                print(False)
                break
        else:
            print(True)

    else:
         print(False)
```

It will return True or False.I need to use this function in a program of mine.The use is like follows:

```
for i in range(0,45): #sample
    if prime(i) == True:
        print(i)
```

What it does is print outputs in the form of True/False but what I require is the number itself

What is wrong with this.How can I correct it as I have to make use of `prime()` function to do the same as above

Comment: Your function should not `print()`, but rather `return` `True` or `False`.

Comment: You have to add return statement and `range(2, num // 2):` should be `range(2, num // 2 + 1):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your function to:

```
def prime(num):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, (num // 2)+1):
            if num % i == 0:
                return False
        else:
            return True

    else:
         return False
```

Comment: I returns True in every case

Comment: @Xtense I don't understand your comment. Could you clarify please?

Comment: I guess my code for ```prime()``` is wrong because for every input its returning True.Could you check please

Comment: It works for me. Could you please elaborate? when I run it for `range(0,45)`, it prints only the prime numbers

Comment: try to run ```prime(4)```,it displays True.Its only taking 4 as a exception

Comment: Error is here: `range(2, num // 2):` should be   `for i in range(2, num//2+1): `

Comment: `num=4` yields `range(2,2)` which is empty. I've updated my solution. Thanks @Pygirl for your comment.

Comment: Understood and received the answer.Could you explain what is difference between print and return.I am a begginer actually

Comment: return allows you to store the value in a variable while print just outputs the value

Answer (score 1):

There are much better ways to find primes in python than this. Try this out:

```
import math
def prime(n):
    for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Could you please explain the logic behind using ```math.sqrt(n) + 1```.

Comment: Even ur code was correct just rather then printing true and false return those values thats it.